# Copy files from /vendor/* to another server? Mailchimp installation without composer

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, mailchimp, 3rd-party-library

My shared hosting doesn't allow me to use composer install (php memory limit error). So I had to install to my clone magento2 on xampp server.

http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/installation-guide-m4m2
below are the two commands i use.

```
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2 1.0.32
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

i can see from my local copy that files are created in

```
vendor\mailchimp\mc-magento2\
vendor\ebizmarts\mailchimp-lib\
```

My question is can I just copy this two folder and upload to my live magento2 server, and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` ?

Comment: If it's only a memory issue I suggest trying to copy over your local composer.json and composer.lock file to the server. Running composer install (that reads the information from the lock file) generally does not require huge amounts of memory,

Comment: By uploading the composer.json and composer.lock files, do I still need to upload those two folders to vendor directory on the live server before running composer install? Thanks

Comment: No, composer will manage the vendor directory for you and download anything that is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, however you can set your own memory limit on demand.

```
php -d memory_limit=512M composer install
```

If not, do as you suggested and run the install somewhere else just `rsync` the `/vendor` folder. However I would recommend to still run the `dumpautoload` on the server

```
php -d memory_limit=512M composer dumpautoload
```

That will generate all the necessary autoloader files for the environment.

However, if running a composer install already gives you memory issues, I don't think `bin/magento` will run without problems.

So I would still do

```
php -d memory_limit=512M bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

EDIT: 
You may need the location of composer to run it as a file with php. In that case you can try

```
php -d memory_limit=512M $(which composer) install
```

Which will substitute the full path of the composer command, so you can run it as a file with PHP.

Comment: if i do it the first way, do i need to copy over the entire /vendor folder, or just the two packages folders  vendor\mailchimp\mc-magento2\ & vendor\ebizmarts\mailchimp-lib\?

Comment: the whole vendor folder